# How to add binding space to memoir twoside

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

I'm using the LED template to MSc which uses `memoir` `twoside`.
I need to print it and it requires extra margins for binding.

How do I simply add the extra space on the spine side of the page?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, makeidx]{memoir}
\input{style.tex}

STYLE.TEX:

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

% *************** Wygląd strony ***************
\settypeblocksize{*}{32pc}{1.618}

\setlrmargins{*}{1.47in}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1.3}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}

\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\checkandfixthelayout

% *************** Stylu rozdziałów i podrozdziałów ***************
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
        \chaptitlefont\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{1em}%
        {##1}\vspace{1em}\hrule height 0.5pt%
        }%
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \chapnumfont\thechapter%
        }%
}

\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
```

Comment: Are line/page breaks allowed to change, or is this a "last-minute" correction that shouldn't affect (most of) the layout?

Comment: Sadly "Last minute". Currently looks great... on screen.

Comment: It's necessary to see the part of the preamble where the page parameters are set.

Comment: Question updated :)

Comment: OK, It seems I found the solution: (at least it worked for me)

\setlrmargins{*}{2cm}{*}

Comment: I have the same problem you posted, however, \setlrmargins{}{2cm}{} gives an latex error for with my code!

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [`memoir` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/memoir), chapter 2, the command `\setlrmargins` is available to adjust margins, with arguments:

```
\setlrmargins{<spine>}{<edge>}{<ratio>}
```

Only one argument could be given, with `*` for the two others *e.g.*

```
\setlrmargins{*}{2cm}{*}
```

There is also a command

```
\setbinding{<length>}
```

that adds to the inner margin to allow for the binding. This should be added after setting the page size, but before setting the margins.